# How do i find data sheet of a seven segment display?

Tags: arduino, led, datasheet

I have a common anode seven segment display, how do I find out it's pin specifications.Nothing is mentioned (product name or number ) on it.

[image]

Comment: We have even less to go on, since there's not even a picture in your post. Probably you will just have to guess.

Comment: It won't take too long to set up a suitable power supply and resistor and just try combinations of pins until you find the anode, then map out the segments 1 by 1.

Comment: Most of those have pretty standard pinouts - post a link to a picture if you cannot post a picture yourself and someone will add it. Otherwise, just take a 5V supply and a 1k resistor and play around with it.

Comment: (1) Too localized.  Deals with a specific commodity part.  (2) Insufficient preliminary research.

Comment: If that picture is the component in question it definitely does have a manufacturer (HP) and number (HDSP 5301, if I read it correctly) on it. If it is not, please post a picture of the correct part!

Answer (score 3):

So here's what I've done.

1. I noticed that your image says www.allspectrum.com on it, so I went to that website.
2. There, I searched for "display", and I looked in the first 20 results.
3. Not surprisingly, I found a [link to the product](http://www.allspectrum.com/store/hp-056-red-segment-single-digit-led-display-common-anode-p-245.html).
4. On that webpage, I found a [link to the datasheet](http://www.allspectrum.com/leds/HP-Agilent/HDSP-5301/hdsp530x.pdf), which should have everything you need.